# How to bind more than one ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observablecollection

How can I implement both of these ObservableCollections in my xaml? I want to have a listview with all my students, and another listview with all my teachers.For now I just made an example student and teacher object. Am I going about this the wrong way. Eventually I will pulling from a datatable, not sure how I would implement it to the ObservableCollection though.

```
     Public Class PersonalViewModel


Public Sub New()

    Dim obcollection1 As New ObservableCollection(Of Student)
    Dim obcollection2 As New ObservableCollection(Of Teacher)

    obcollection1.Add(New Student("W0332309", "Tony", "Thetiger", "Male"))

    obcollection2.Add(New Teacher)

    'I Cant set datacontext here cause 1.) this isn't a window 2.) I can only set datacontext once anyway
    'So how to do it in xaml?


End Sub

End Class
```

xaml:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <local:PersonalViewModel x:Key="personalviewmodel"></local:PersonalViewModel>

</Page.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source= {StaticResource personalviewmodel}}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,42,0,67" Name="ListView1" Width="166" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LName}" />
                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>
         </ListView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make the two collections public members of your ViewModel. Then in the XAML you set the DataContext to he ViewModel and bind the Listboxes to the relevant public members in the bound model.

**Update**: Here is a simple but hopefully complete example

Here is the Model code, not that I only defined a Student class and demonstrated a very naive implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. I reused the Student class for the teachers collection so I hope that does not cause confusion.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class PersonalViewModel
  Private _students As New ObservableCollection(Of Student)
  Public ReadOnly Property Students As ObservableCollection(Of Student)
    Get
      Return _students
    End Get
  End Property

  Private _teachers As New ObservableCollection(Of Student)
  Public ReadOnly Property Teachers As ObservableCollection(Of Student) ' This should be a Teacher class
    Get
      Return _teachers
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub New()
    _students.Add(New Student("Tony", "Thetiger"))
    _teachers.Add(New Student("Cindy", "Thecougar"))
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class Student
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private _firstName As String
  Private _lastName As String

  Public Sub New(firstName As String, lastName As String)
    Me.FirstName = firstName
    Me.LastName = lastName
  End Sub

  Public Property FirstName As String
    Get
      Return _firstName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      If value <> _firstName Then
        _firstName = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"))
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property LastName As String
    Get
      Return _lastName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      If value <> _lastName Then
        _lastName = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"))
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

For the XAML, I have just used a Window but the same applies for Page. Note that I bind the grid container to the Model and then each of the ListViews to the respective collection.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModelBindDemo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:PersonalViewModel x:Key="model" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>      
    </ListView>

    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: U mean like creating two separate collection properties? Any possible way u can give me an example? :)

Comment: @TMan, correct. I will put together an example and post it here, I normally use C# so I will make a best effort at VB.NET translation.

Comment: Perfect..thanks a lot, this was exactly it. I had it right in the code, I just didn't know how to implement it in the xaml. Thanks :)